# Android - Open PDF File from a secure Server (Login required)

Tags: android, security, file, pdf, authentication

I have a really specfific question.

I'm developing an Android / iPhone app for my school. 
This should display PDF File from a secure server. 
That's how it works:

I open the webpage (edunite.com/login.aspx) in a normal webview. If the webview has loaded the page I sign in by using Javascript:

```
    view.loadUrl("javascript: var field = document.getElementById('TextBoxEmail');  field.value='XYXYXY@go.de' ");
           view.loadUrl("javascript:var field = document.getElementById('TextBoxPassword');      field.value='XYXYXYX';");
```

That works perfectly fine. 
After logging in I get the Session ID from the URL this looks like this:
 (S(a2kolt553yeyfq454f55eo45))

Then I load a URL, where I can find my PDF file... 
That looks like this: 
https://secure.edunite.info/(S(mhgkyc45ber4zcm1xcyhdn45))/StudentPortal/Document/MainFolderList.aspx

I have to do this, because the link of the URL changes daily.

By using the HTML file I am able to locate the URL to my PDF File. 
So that's all right an works perfectly.

### NOW LET'S COME TO THE REAL PROBLEM:

I can't open the pdf URL in the webview, because Androids webview does not support .pdf Files. 
I can't download the file and send it to a local installed reader, because if I want to download it it says, that it is not logged in.

That's alright, because I'm only logged in on my webview. 
I can't sign in with a Http Client, because then my SessionID would be different and so the URL differs, too.

I really don't get the clue. It would be very nice, if somebody could help me.

For example on the iPhone it works perfectly, because the UIWebView supports .pdf Files.

Comment: Since the stock WebView doesn't support pdf files I think your only option is to download the file and load it into a PDF reader. Unless you want to go to the trouble of creating your own PDF viewer that can work with a remote file. The ideal solution (from android point of view) is if the pdf content could be converted to html so it can be displayed with the stock WebView, that may not be an option for your file though.

Comment: Thanks, your last idea could help me I'll try that.

The thing is that I can't download the file. I can 'load' it into the webview, but I cannnot get it from there and I cannot display it

Comment: @Sn0wfreeze did u get any solution for it?